# What are IO ports, serial ports and what's the difference between them?

Tags: operating-system, bochs

I'm confused.

I have recently started working on building an operating system while using bochs as an emulator and a certain manual online.

In the manual to move the vga framebuffer cursor I'm using the IO ports using the command 'out'. I get how to control it but I don't know what is it that I'm controlling, and after some reading it seems like everywhere it was addressed as an abstract thing that for example makes the cursor to change its position on the screen.

What I want to know: what are they physically? are they cables? if yes from where to where they are connected? can I input from them also as there name suggest? and why do I need the out command and cant write directly to their place in the memory?

If in your answer you can also include the serial ports and the difference between them and the IO ones it will be amazing,

with respect,
revolution

(btw the operating system is 32 bits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An IO port is basically memory on the motherboard that you can write/read. The motherboard makes some memory available other than RAM. The CPU has a control bus which allows it to "tell" the motherboard that what it outputs on the data bus is to be written somewhere else than RAM. When you output to the VGA buffer, you write to video memory on the motherboard. The out/in instructions are used to write/read IO ports instead of writing to RAM. When you use out/in instructions, you instruct the CPU to set a certain line on its control bus to tell the motherboard to write/read a certain byte to an IO port instead of RAM.

Today, a lot of RAM memory is used for hardware mapping instead of IO ports. This is often called the PCI hole. It is memory mapped IO. So you will write to RAM and it will send the data to hardware like graphics memory. All of this is transparent to OS developers. You are simply using very abstract hardware interfaces which are either conventional (open source) or proprietary.

Serial ports in the meantime are simply ports which are serial in nature. A serial port is defined to be a port where data is transferred one bit at a time. USB is serial (universal serial bus). VGA is serial and others are too. These ports are not like IO ports. You can output to them indirectly using IO ports.

IO ports offer various hardware interfaces which allow to drive hardware. For example, if you have a VGA compatible screen and set text mode, the motherboard will make certain IO ports available and, when you write to these IO ports, video memory will vary depending on what you output to these ports. Eventually, the VGA screen will refresh when the video controller will output data written to video memory through the actual VGA port. I'm not totally aware of how all of this works since I'm not an electrical engineer and I never read about this stuff. To what I know, you can see the pins of the VGA port and what they do independently on wikipedia. VGA works with RGBHV. RGB stands for red, green and blue while HV stand for horizontal/vertical sync. As stated on wiki in the article on analog television:

> Synchronizing pulses added to the video signal at the end of every scan line and video frame ensure that the sweep oscillators in the receiver remain locked in step with the transmitted signal so that the image can be reconstructed on the receiver screen. A sync separator circuit detects the sync voltage levels and sorts the pulses into horizontal and vertical sync.
>
> The horizontal synchronization pulse (horizontal sync, or HSync), separates the scan lines. The horizontal sync signal is a single short pulse which indicates the start of every line. The rest of the scan line follows, with the signal ranging from 0.3 V (black) to 1 V (white), until the next horizontal or vertical synchronization pulse.

Memory in itself takes various forms in hardware. Video memory is often called VRAM (Video RAM) or the Frame Buffer as you can read in a Wikipedia article. So in itself video memory is an array of DRAM. DRAM today is one capacitor (which stores the data) and one mosfet transistor (which controls the flow of the data). So you have special wiring on the motherboard between the data bus of the processor and the VRAM. When you output data to video memory, you write to VRAM on the motherboard. Where you write and how just depends on the video mode you set up.

Most modern systems work with HDMI/Display port along with graphics card. These graphics card are other hardware interfaces which are often complex and they often cannot be known because the drivers for the cards are provided by the manufacturers. osdev.org has information on Intel HD Graphics which has a special interface to interact with. It can be used to gather info on the monitor and to determine what RAM address to use to write to the monitor.

Comment: Usually a serial port means a UART port, *not* any other protocol which is also serial.

Comment: And to be clear: a serial port is an actual connector on the back of your computer (at least in the old days) but an IO port is a bit like a memory address. Completely different meanings of "port"

Comment: Yes IO ports are memory on the motherboard while I'd prefer calling Serial ports "slots" on the motherboard.

Comment: I have read your answer and I can confidently say that I understand the concept better now because of it, but for clearance I have to ask: after I'm writing to the IO ports which as you said are memory on the motherboard, the CPU which constantly scans it takes the data and copies it to the suitable hardware device?

Comment: The CPU doesn't scan the IO ports. IO ports can be polled by the controller of a hardware device. I would say the motherboard is responsible to make VRAM vary according to what you output on the IO ports in the case of VGA video memory. Hardware like CPU, screen or hard-drive is plugged into slots on the motherboard. This hardware presents hardware interfaces to the motherboard that it can use to talk to hardware. As an example of IO port use, you can look at the article on PIO mode for hard drives. The IO port 0x1f7 is used to send commands to the drive which then executes that command.

Comment: Ok, but how does the motherboard knows when the changed is occurred in the IO ports? There is a certain reaction to notify it when the IO ports of the VGA has changed? (According to what you wrote in this case the motherboard is the hardware controller hence it got to know somehow when the ports value changes)

Comment: I'm not totally sure. I would guess that when you write commands to an IO port, it is propagated to the targeted hardware device immediately. For example, if you send a read command to the IO port 0x1f7 targeting an hard-drive, the hard-drive will immediately be notified and will start moving its parts to provide with the request. Communication from hardware to the CPU is done using interrupts. Hardware will raise a certain IRQ which is attached to a certain INT number which is itself attached to a certain ISR (handler). The handler will run and answer the request.

Comment: For example, keyboard is often connected to IRQ 1. So, when you press a key, you close a current loop which is going to send a signal to the IOAPIC. The IOAPIC can be programmed to throw any INTerrupt number. For example, if the IOAPIC is programmed to throw INT 10 for IRQ 1 then INT 10's ISR (interrupt service routine) will run. This handler will probably look at the application which has focus and send a message to this application stating that a keyboard key was pressed. On windows, it works exactly that way. Every window application is polling a message queue in a loop.

Comment: BTW memory-mapped I/O works exactly the same way, and people stopped making new I/O ports because they decided memory-mapped I/O was better. Memory addresses are very similar to I/O ports except you access them with MOV instead of IN or OUT